# can moment.locale take a parameter of locale?

Tags: date, momentjs

date="01/23/1993"; MM/DD/YYYY
moment(date).format();

the above formats the date string to a dateObj

but is there a way that i can format the date based on the locale.

say if the locale = en-GB,
and the date= "23/01/1993",
moment(date).format(); gives back "Invalid Date" instead can moment take a parameter of locale and give back correct dateObj ?

Comment: fixed it by doing below const dateFormat = Moment.localeData(navigator.language).longDateFormat('L'); date=moment(date,dateFormat).format();